# Learning RoR first project CS169 edX

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on the second homework, for reference this is a completed version http://alexandre-alcobia.herokuapp.com/movies I can't seem to get my "Movie Title" and "Release Date" headers to become links.
I kind of think there's something wrong view file, but I'm also including the relevant portion of the Controller because when I manually include ?sort=title to end of the URI it doesn't end up sorted.

Here's the MoviesController.rb

```
    class MoviesController < ApplicationController
    ...
      def index
        @movies = Movie.all unless params["sort"] == nil
        @movies = Movie.order('movies.title').all if params["sort"] == "title"
        @movies = Movie.order('movies.release_date').all if params["sort"] == "release_date"
      end
    ...
    end
```

and here's index.html.haml

```
    -#  This file is app/views/movies/index.html.haml
    %h1 All Movies
    %table#movies
      %thead
        %tr
          %th{:class => @title_header}
            = link_to "Movie Title", {:sort => :title}, {:id => :title_header}
          %th Rating
          %th{:class => @release_header}
            = link_to "Release Date", {:sort => :release_date}, {:id => :release_header}
          %th More Info
      %tbody
        - @movies.each do |movie|
          %tr
            %td= movie.title 
            %td= movie.rating
            %td= movie.release_date
            %td= link_to "More about #{movie.title}", movie_path(movie)

= link_to 'Add new movie', new_movie_path
```

Also I haven't started the filter by rating portion so just ignore that in the example.

Edit: here's the error mentioned in the comments below

```
undefined method `order' for #<Array:0xae00ad8>
```

and here's some of the framework trace (no idea what this means... sorry for the wall of text)

```
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run__379635507__process_action__868408152__callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:53:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:201:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:193:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:65:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:152:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:96:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:95:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.8.3) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:141:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:531:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:243:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:326:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:62:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:455:in `call'
railties (3.1.0) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.0) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Eek sorry about the poorly formatted code its my first time posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Rails 4? This should work

```
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
    @movies.order!(:title) if params["sort"] == "title"
    @movies.order!(:release_date) if params["sort"] == "release_date"
  end
```

If you are using Rails 3, modify your controller like this instead:

```
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
    @movies = @movies.order(:title) if params["sort"] == "title"
    @movies = @movies.order(:release_date) if params["sort"] == "release_date"
  end
```

What ever is you Rails version, your links should look like this:

```
  = link_to "Movie Title", movies_path(:sort => 'title'), {:id => :title_header}
  ...
  = link_to "Release Date", movies_path(:sort => 'release_date'), {:id => :release_header}
```

Comment: I'm using rails 3, that code didn't work, I changed @movies to Movie and then the one for `:title` worked but the one for `:release_date` gave me a weird error (its worth noting that content of sqlite database for the release_date field is of type timedate.) I'll add the first few lines of the framework trace to post since its far to long for a comment.

Comment: I added the Rails 3 way in my answer, accept it if its helpful